# Make GWT interact with REST Architecture in PHP

Tags: php, gwt, rest

On my localhost,I have an already made REST Architecture. I need to make a GWT application to interact with the REST Interface.The Architecture returns JSON format data which I need to parse with GWT. Does someone have an idea how to make this?

Edit:
I have a service running at http://localhost/recess/restApp/comment, which returns a JSON like this `{"Action":"GetComments","ActionStatus":1,"CommentIds":["4","5","7"]}, I need to get this,

Normally, GWT runs a java servlet, so how do i change this??

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

1. AutoBeans
2. JS Overlay Types

Use [JS Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) to make your JS objects available to Java/GWT code, and [`JsonUtils`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html) to parse JSON to your overlay types.

In the event you couldn't use overlay types, have a look at [`JSONParser`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html) (cumbersome API unfortunately). `JSONObject` is also the only way to serialize an overlay type to JSON (wrap it in a `JSONObject` then call `toString()`).

The alternative is [`AutoBean`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean). The main (if not only) advantage is to make your code reusable in other Java apps (such as an Android client, or in a Java servlet calling your PHP service). Otherwise, it mostly saves you from writing JSNI (on declare methods in an interface and possibly annotate them with `@PropertyName`)

The answer wouldn't be complete if it didn't mention [`JsonpRequestBuilder`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html) (there's also RequestFactory with [`JsonRpcService`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/JsonRpcService.html) but it's about JSON-RPC –not quite RESTful– and is still experimentatl)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [GWTs support for JSON](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON.html)?

Comment: That doc unfortunately is outdated and gives very bad advice.