# Why use JSNI and overlay types to represent the JSON object returned from the server in GWT project?

Tags: json, gwt, jsni

I was reading the link: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html and found that the JSNI and overlay types are used to decode the JSON data from the server side.

```
    // Send request to server and catch any errors.
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

    try {
      Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
          displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
          if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
            updateTable(JsonUtils.<JsArray<StockData>>safeEval(response.getText()));
          } else {
            displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON (" + response.getStatusText()
                + ")");
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
      displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
    }
```

Why does it use the JsonUtils.>safeEval(response.getText()) to decode the JSON data? Does it have to do so? Is this the only way to receive the JSON data when using GWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not the only way. However, JsonUtils.safeEval will either make use of the browser's built-in (i.e. native, so assumed to be the fastest way to do it) `JSON.parse()` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse for more details), which will turn a JSON string into a JavaScript Object.

In turn, overlay types let you write Java code which directly maps to a JavaScript object, making it very simple and easy to talk about the underlying JS data, from your normal Java code.

Of course there are other options as well, off the top of my head, you can use `JSONObject` class in the `com.google.gwt.json.client` package - this still does the `JSON.parse()` call, but then exposes data through a map- and list-like structure for your Java code. Additionally, AutoBeans make it possible to declare interfaces that describe the structure of the data, and read from the JSON string (or a JavaScript object) into those interfaces - it lets your code behave more like Java with built-in collections and such, at the cost of some performance to translate back and forth.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15876202/116472, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685489/116472 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/8212611/116472 for the various built-in options to parse JSON in GWT.